# outputLimits Matlab equivalent for python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert a matlab code to python, unfortunately I am facing the problem that I don't find an equivalent of the matlab function `outputLimits`.
The function is suppose to :
**Estimate the output spatial limits corresponding to a set of input spatial limits, xLimitsIn and yLimitsIn, given 2-D geometric transformation tform**.
Maybe it exists an equivalent in opencv but I can't find it.
The matlab source is : https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affinetform2d.outputlimits.html

Answer (score 0):

If you take the corner points of the original image, and transform them using the tform matrix, you will get their new location. These new locations will be the output limits of the new image.